# Core Data / NSFetchedResultsController - Registering changed objects related to the fetched object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get a list of objects which is displayed in a `UITableView`. If I change values in the objects the whole thing triggers and automatically reloads the changed rows. But one of the displayed values comes from related objects (one-to many relationship). Those objects have a transient title (so it's value comes again from another object). When this title changes the rows are not reloaded.

**Question:** Can anybody suggest a clean solution to this?

**Possible Dirty Solution:** I could create a transient property in the class which gets fetched with a "fake" setter method, so the `NSFetchedResultsController` will see a change and trigger a reload. But that's very dirty in my opinion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FRC` tracks changes in properties of objects of one particular entity. Changes in objects of related entity are therefore not tracked. But you can use KVO to trigger `FRC` reaction.

```
[Department].employees <->> [Employee].department
```

In `Employee.m`:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:title forKey:@"title"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];

    [self.department willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"];
    [self.department didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"];
}
```

Or something like this (haven't tested it myself, though):

```
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [super didChangeValueForKey:key];

    if (self.department && [key isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [self.department willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"];
        [self.department didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"];
    }
}
```