# Detect changes to single coredata entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-observing

I have the following coredata entities:

```
@interface Car (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Part *> *parts;

@end

@interface Part (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Car *car;

@end
```

This is a one to many relationship between car and parts.  In one of my view controllers I display a car view with all parts.  I want to listen for changes to the parts of the car.

I thought this would be easy enough with KVO.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.car addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"parts" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];
}
```

then:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([@"parts" isEqualToString:keyPath]) {
        // do what I need to do with new parts
    }
}
```

However when I pull changes from a server to update a car parts I am getting unexpected callbacks to the observeValueForKeyPath method even when I do not change any parts.

Wondering if faulting could be the problem:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH18-SW7

Was hoping to use KVO, but maybe with coredata objects its just not a great idea.  Am I doing something wrong or should I use an alternative?

If I should not be using KVO, I believe my other options are:
1. Listen for MOC changes.  This is not great as I don't really know what changed on the object.
2. Implement a FetchedResultsController  on parts with a predicate to find only the car I am interested in.  Seems like a bit of overkill, but I think this will give me what I need.

Answer (score 5):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is the preferred way to observe changes in some data subset.

And for single object you can observe changes in `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(contextDidChange:)
           name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
         object:context];
```

When notification arrives, process its `userInfo`:

```
- (void)contextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = notification.object;
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

    NSArray *invalidatedAll = userInfo[NSInvalidatedAllObjectsKey];
    NSSet *invalidated      = userInfo[NSInvalidatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deleted          = userInfo[NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *updated          = userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *refreshed        = userInfo[NSRefreshedObjectsKey];

    // context reset
    if (invalidatedAll) {
        // probably you better have to dismiss your VC here.
        return;
    }

    // invalidated
    if ([invalidated containsObject:self.car]) {
        // it make sense to dismiss here too.
        return;
    }

    // deleted
    if ([deleted containsObject:self.car]) {
        // and here.
        return;
    }

    // refreshed
    if ([refreshed containsObject:self.car]) {
        // update your interface.
        return;
    }

    // updated
    if ([updated containsObject:self.car]) {
        // update your interface.
        return;
    }
}
```

To receive notifications about `Car` object when related `Parts` updated, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794349/826716).

You can get list of changed attributes from [changedValues](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506775-changedvalues?language=objc) property.

Don't forget to unsubscribe:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        removeObserver:self
                  name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                object:context];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's that conception implemented as a `UIViewController` category:
[BTDependentVC](https://github.com/bteapot/BTDependentVC)