# Observe changes on CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

On one of my screens, I'm adding a product to a Shopping Cart

Like this:

```
extension ShoppingCart {
        @NSManaged public var products: NSSet?
    }

    .../

    let shoppingCart = ShoppingCart(context: CoreDataService.managedObjectContext)

    let product = Product(context: CoreDataService.managedObjectContext)
    product.title = "iPhone"
    
    shoppingCart.addToProducts(product)

    CoreDataService.saveContext()
```

And I want my other screen (next one on the tab bar) to observe these changes and display a table view with products.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Not sure if this exist but you should be able to do so by notifying changes via an extension of CoreDataService. make a `saveContextAndNotify` that calls `saveContext` AND sends an NSNotification

Comment: so I can't directly connect my Shopping Cart VC to Core Data and observe these changes? Only via NCenter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370802/detect-changes-to-single-coredata-entity looks like this is what you're trying to achieve. I was just passing by and thought this could help

Answer (score 0):

Core Data publishes the changes in the Entities.

In your other view (the one with the table of products), you can use the following properties to store the items you want to present:

```
@ObservedObject var shoppingCart: ShoppingCart
@ObservedObject var product: Product             // If necessary

init() {
    ...    // Initialize the above properties using/ passing the same instance used in the other views
}
```